# Fix "too many authentication failures"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a user account on a machine where they attempted to log in with the incorrect password via SSH until it triggered "too many authentication failures for X" -- I have access ot the box as the root user, but how do i reset this user accounts login?

I've tried:

```
faillog -u username -r
```

but this does not seem to resolve the problem for that user account

Comment: Try this `ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host` to see what happens.

Comment: Just restart sshd and it will clear it up.

Source: I set MaxAuthTries to 2, locked an account, restarted sshd, it worked fine. It won't kill existing connections.

Answer (score 2):

you can fix this without restarting the ssh service. First figure out if it is really a failed login issues by,

```
pam_tally2 -u <user>.
```

(if its RH5x, pam_tally2 with pam_tally)

If its due to failed login attempts, you can issue the following command to reset the number of login attempts to 0,

```
pam_tally2 -r -u <user>
```